# updating data from dynamic form properly laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I have 2 models

`Tour.php`

```
public function Itinerary()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Itinerary', 'tour_id');
}
```

and

`Itinerary.php`

```
public function tour() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Tour', 'tour_id');
}
```

`tours` table:

`id|title|content`

`itineraries` table:

`id|tour_id|day|plan`

My store method looks like this:

```
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
  $tour = new Tour;
  $tour->title            = $request->title;
  $tour->content          = $request->content;
  $tour->save();

  $itineraries = [];
  $day        = $request->input('day');
  $plan  = $request->input('itinerary');
  foreach ($day as $i => $name) {
      $itineraries[] = new Itinerary([
          'tour_id' => $tour->id,
          'plan' => $plan[$i],
          'day' => $day[$i],
      ]);
  }
  $tour->itinerary()->saveMany($itineraries);
  Session::flash('success','Tour is sucessfully created !');
  return redirect()->route('tour.show',$tour->id);
}
```

And following code for the update method:

```
public function update(Request $request, Tour $tour)
{
  $tour->title            = $request->title;
  $tour->content          = $request->content;
  $tour->save();

  $count = count($request->input('day'));
  $temp_day        = $request->input('day');
  $temp_itinerary  =   $request->input('itinerary');
  $tour_id        = $tour->id;
  $itinerary = Itinerary::where('tour_id', $tour_id);

  for($i = 0; $i <$count; ++$i) 
  {
  $itinerary->updateOrCreate([
  'tour_id' => $tour_id,
  'plan' => $temp_itinerary[$i],
  'day' => $temp_day[$i]
  ]);
}
    Session::flash('success','Tour updated sucessfully !');
    return redirect()->route('tour.show',$tour->id);
}
```

The trouble I'm having is the update method is adding new additional rows instead of updating.

After creating tour and itinerary:[image: After creating tour and itinerary]

After updating tour and itinerary [image: After updating tour and itinerary]

I have added additional data `day3` & `day4` but the code created new row with data `day2`not but not for `day1`. It has been boggling my mind since last week. What am I missing here or should I use different approach to for CRUD operation on  `itineraries` table. Please suggest.

Comment: It looks like you have your relationships backwards in your models. The seem to be referencing themselves.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I corrected it. The mistake was here only. I must have missed out in hurry.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the updateOrCreate function works differently than you think. It can take two arrays. If no model exists which matches all of the values given in the first array, a new one is created.

In your case, you only use the first parameter for updateOrCreate, so you are saying "If no tour exists with exactly this id, plan, and day: create a new one with these values."

So if you would like to update each tour solely by whether or not an existing tour matches the current ID, change this:

```
$itinerary->updateOrCreate(
    ['tour_id' => $tour_id, 'plan' => $temp_itinerary[$i], 'day' => $temp_day[$i]]
);
```

To this:

```
$itinerary->updateOrCreate(
    ['tour_id' => $tour_id], 
    ['plan' => $temp_itinerary[$i], 'day' => $temp_day[$i]]
);
```

edit: check out the (brief) documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models.

Comment: The code snippet you suggested is updating and saving one row (last one) only. I had inserted datas`tour_id:1 | day:1 | plan: plan1`  while creating itinerary and added additional data `tour_id:1 | day:2 | plan: plan2`  and `tour_id:1 | day:3 | plan: plan3`. But only `tour_id:1 | day:3 | plan: plan3` is being saved in the table.

Comment: Can you suggest any other alternative approach to insert and update itinerary table ?

Comment: I'm not sure what could be happening there. I'll take a second look in a bit. 
Personally, I don't fiddle with updateOrCreate or similar functions. I'd just grab an instance of an itinerary with `$itinerary = Itinerary::find($itinerary_id)`, set its values, and save it with `$itinerary->save();`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if the user deletes particular dynamic input then whether above code will delete that record and updates others records? If any

Please clarify